# How to switch between projects in Bugherd that have the same URL?

Tags: debugging, browser-extension, bug-tracking

I have two project in BugHerd that use the same URL. Let's call them "Users" and "Stakeholders" (we want to keep their feedback separate). I can easily switch between projects in BugHerd, but when I "Open website", the BugHerd sidebar always shows the "Users" project. How do I get the website sidebar to change to the "Stakeholders" project?

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding the the BugHerd header javascript for both projects to the site header.